# sending form values $form_state['redirect'] Form API Drupal

Tags: forms, redirect, drupal, submit, drupal-forms

I want to send my form values using form API drupal. I have following value

```
 $form['billing']["cardholders_name"] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("Cardholder's Name"),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#prefix' => '<div class="field-wrapper-w1 card-name">'
);
```

I am writing following code in my form submit function

```
function test_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

$form_state['redirect'] = 'www.test.com/page' . '?cname=' .  $form_state['values']['billing[cardholders_name]'];
```

}

But it seems like it is not working. Please help

Answer (score 0):

The following example appears in

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7

```
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
  'node/123',
  array(
    'query' => array(
      'foo' => 'bar',
    ),
    'fragment' => 'baz',
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Any value for form element will be in $form_state under values so in your function test_form_submit you can access cardholders_name

```
$form_state['values']['cardholders_name']
```

also you can do it in this way using drupal_goto()

```
 drupal_goto('www.test.com/page' . '?cname=' .  $form_state['values']['cardholders_name]);
```